# History of special quadratic reciprocity $(-3/p)_2$ and $(5/p)_2$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14533/special-quadratic-reciprocity-3-p-2-and-5-p-2-in-addition-to-1-p-2

asks about the history of special cases of quadratic reciprocity that are understandable for "geometric" reasons. I'm curious whether Euler or Lagrange knew these cases before Gauss. I'd imagine that Franz Lemmermeyer @franzlemmermeyer knows this very well, but I only belatedly realized that he is not attending the history of science and math stack exchange...

Comment: my impression is that   @usename  inside a question does not sne a notification to that user. I know it fails inside an answer.

Comment: Hm, thanks @WillJagy

Comment: Trying to ping Franz L, by @franzlemmermeyer ...

Comment: ... or @lemmermeyer ...

Answer (score 2):

Franz L. kindly has responded to my query/queries by email, and I quoted his response as an answer to that other question.

If people here think this question should be deleted, that's fine... although I did realize, after posting the question on the History of Math and Science, that that site does not include some important scholars, who *are* present here...

Dunno what to do... :)